# Broadcast receiver not receiving intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have two apps that I have complete control over.  Both are signed with the same cert and both use the exact same intent filter.  One sends the broadcast from a fragment, the other is suppose to receive it and do something.  This however is not working:

```
Strings.FILTER_INIT_REGISTER = "com.app.FILTER_INIT_REGISTER"

Intent intent = new Intent(Strings.FILTER_INIT_REGISTER);
getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

I have registered the receiver in the Manifest app tag for the app containing the ReportingReceiver class:

```
<receiver             
    android:name=".receivers.ReportingReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.app.FILTER_INIT_REGISTER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />                
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Curious why the ReportingReceiver class is not getting the intent call?

Comment: I am not sure the category of the broadcast is "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" if you do not specify any category while broadcasting. Have you tried either to remove the category tag or to addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT) while broadcasting?

Comment: What's your Application Tag contain in Manifest?

Comment: App tag only has a service and respective receiver tags within it.

Comment: Removing the category decoration makes no difference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your application only has a service and receivers then this won't work in Android 3.1 and later. The reason is that the system will not send broadcast Intents to application that are in the **STOPPED STATE**. An application is in the **STOPPED STATE** when it is first installed. It is removed from the **STOPPED STATE** when the user manually starts the application for the first time. It is returned to the **STOPPED STATE** if the user forces the application to stop using the application manager tool.

Since your application has no Activities, there is no way for the user to "start" it. Therefore it will never come out of the stopped state.

See http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols

Comment: Add this to the intent: intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @Android Addict: can you tell me please why broadcast receiver stop receiving intent from service if any network exception occurred in service whether i am sending broadcast in every case else exception too.

Comment: @NeonWarge You should open a new question if you have  problem that isn't answered here. Your comment isn't particularly useful as you say nothing about your situation. Commenting here about your situation isn't the right thing to do anyway. Please open a new question.

Answer (score 7):

As Android Addict says in his comment to David Wasser's answer ... there is a way around this behaviour.

Just add the following flag to the calling Intent. This will ensure that you also reach broadcast receivers from "stopped" applications.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES

You can read more about this Android 3.1 change here

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols

and here

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18225

Comment: Thanks, the middle link lead me to *Note that the system adds FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES to all broadcast intents.*, which was what I was looking for.