# BroadcastReceiver stops receiving after few days (Local Notification)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I'm using a BroadCastReceiver for triggering alarm which is working fine for like 2-3 days, after that it stops working, I am not receiving any alerts in my BroadcastReceiver.
Is there a lifeSpan for Pending Intent?
Actually I'm creating alarms for 30 days. I'm using PendingIntents. Here is the code for PendingIntent:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntentScheduler = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);            
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntentScheduler);
```

and the receiver at BroadcastReceiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     this.context = context;        
     Log.d("onReceive", "this is broadcast reciever");        
}
```

Android Manifest Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
  <application>
  <receiver android:name=".medicine.modal.AlarmReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"
            android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:process=":remote">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.healthsaverz.nimap.healthmobile.healthsaverz.mainscreen.controller.NotificationActivity" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
   </application>
```

Comment: This answer may help

Refer this link

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12829487/2768515

Comment: Has the device been restarted? If the device restarts, all the alarms are gone.

Comment: for that i am checking the condition `if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            //Recreating Pending Intents
        }`.  This is working fine after restarting device.

Comment: is there a lifespan for alarmmanager/pending intent? That might be causing the issue. What say?

Comment: I found a solution, not legitimate but a bypass. May be this will help someone. 
What I did is put a repeating Alarm which repeats at every 24 hours, in which I'm recreating all the Pending Intents. Since the life of pending intent is 2-3 days (According to what i found in my app). This results in creating new Pending Intents everyday.
If anyone finds a better way, please share.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, not legitimate but a bypass. May be this will help someone. What I did is put a repeating Alarm which repeats at every 24 hours, in which I'm recreating all the Pending Intents. Since the life of pending intent is 2-3 days (According to what i found in my app). This results in creating new Pending Intents everyday.